# Logical operator ↓ question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

I am reading ***Discrete Mathematics with its Applications*** by ***Rosen***. I am trying to self learn discrete math. I am actually able to do most questions but I have a question about a solution (not the question itself.)

The question is (Section 1.3 Foundations: Logic and Proofs. Question 51)

**Question** : **Find a compound proposition logically equivalent to p → q using only the logical operator ↓**

**My answer**:

I know

**p → q ≡ ¬ p ∨ q**

and

**p ↓ p ≡ ¬ p**

By combining them, I got the answer:

**((p ↓ p) ↓ q) ↓ (p ↓ p) ↓ q) )**

which is the same answer as the one in the solution manual; however, the manual also lists:

**F ↓ (( F ↓ q ) ↓ q )**

I know **F** is contradiction.

How can I simplify

**((p ↓ p) ↓ q) ↓ (p ↓ p) ↓ q) )**

to

<strike>**F ↓ (( F ↓ q ) ↓ q )**</strike>  (Thanks @Manx)

**F ↓ (( F ↓ p ) ↓ q )**

Comment: Is F= P AND (NOT Q) ? and implement this using NOR gate and compare with urs ?

Comment: I think F = either (p ∧ ¬p) or (q ∧ ¬ q). P AND (NOT Q) is not a contradiction, @Balaji-sb

Comment: I am guessing it will be X=((NOT P) OR Q) and F= X AND (NOT X). See if it comes with this expression ?

Comment: Do you have a typo, F ↓ (( F ↓ q ) ↓ q ) should be F ↓ (( F ↓ p ) ↓ q )? or the book has a typo I guess.

Comment: <strike> **F ↓ (( F ↓ q ) ↓ q )** </strike> should be
 **F ↓ (( F ↓ p ) ↓ q )** Thanks @Manx